# How to align horizontally nav bar in css?

Tags: html, css

my nav bar aligns vertically and i cant align it in a horizontal way. thanks

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: top;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: CSS isn't helpful without the corresponding HTML. Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: show you html code too or create a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to visualise what the nav bars aligned vertically and horizontally. But if the elements are beside each other you have to make them both

```
display: inline-block;
```

And give them both a width, ie `width: 50%;`

If one is above another one, then you can use text-align on both.

Do you have a screencap or a jsfiddle? Then I could help you more.